# How to apply a sort function to a string.find( ) to print results alphabetically?

Tags: c++, function, sorting

I have a program that reads a text file into a struct (members- str author and str title) and gives the user the option to display all records in the file, search for an author, or search for a title. Now I need to integrate a sort function into this process, so that when the user searches by author or title the results are listed alphabetically.

The following sort function works perfectly with my showAll function, but I have absolutely no idea how I can modify my search functions to alphabetize the results.

Sort function code:

```
void sortByTitle(int counter){
    //variable
    int a, b, minIndex;
    string temp;


    for (a = 0; a < counter; a++){
        minIndex = a;
        for (b = a + 1; b < counter - 1; b++){
            if (books[b].title < books[minIndex].title){
                minIndex = b;
            }
       }
        if(minIndex != a) {
            temp = books[a].title;
            books[a].title = books[minIndex].title;
            books[minIndex].title = temp;
            cout << books[a].title << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my current title search function:

```
int showBooksByTitle(int counter, string bookTitle){
    int recordCount = 0;
    //find the user-input string inside bookTitle
    for (int a = 0; a < counter; a++){ //loop through the whole file
       if (books[a].title.find(bookTitle) != string::npos){

            //print a matching record
            cout << books[a].title << " " << "(" << books[a].author << endl;

            //keep track of the number of matching records
            recordCount++;
        }
    }
    return recordCount;
}
```

My assignment specifies these function headers, that the search functions return the number of records found, and that the data be read into a struct (rather than a vector). So I have to leave those aspects as they are.

How can I apply the selection sort to the search function so that I can print the records in order?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here you set

```
smallestIndex = index;
```

then you check if

```
books[index].title < books[smallestIndex].title
```

It appears you are trying to implement a selection sort. A good snippet can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Furhtermore:

- I don't see the need for declaring `loc` outside the for-loop. say `for(int loc...`.
- There is an abundance of sorting algorithms on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and you can use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).
- In the second line you shadow `index` with the same variable in the
  for-loop.
- I don't know how you store `books`, but if you would use std::vector you don't have to pass `counter` every time. You can just use `books.size()`.